# Elasticsearch get search results in batches?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

When I am querying Elasticsearch with the Python Elasticsearch API, I get around 5000 results. Setting the "size" parameter in the search query to a larger number than the number of results leads to the following Java OOM error:

```
File "MGDFinder.py", line 114, in <module>
  res = es.search(index="_all", body=queryMaker(state))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 68, in _wrapped
  return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 440, in search
  params=params, body=body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 276, in perform_request
  status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 55, in perform_request
  self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 97, in _raise_error
  raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, u'OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]')
```

I notice that this happens when the size is set to even just 700. I don't want to increase my Java heap size. Is there a way I can perform my search in batches of 500?

Comment: It's better to use search_after https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-search-after.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can batch request without increasing `Java Heap Space`, The server still will store 5000 results and return.

I think you can use `scroll` to get requests, `scroll` can retrieve quickly from large numbers of results, It likes the `cursor` in traditional database.

The Sample Request:

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/world/test/_search?scroll=1m&pretty' -d '
{
    "size": 50,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}'
```

The Sample Response:

```
{
  "_scroll_id" : "cXVlcnlUaGVuRmV0Y2g7NTszNjpXZW9lRnJXSFItT0U2YUtIM1hOa0FBOzM3Oldlb2VGcldIUi1PRTZhS0gzWE5rQUE7Mzg6V2VvZUZyV0hSLU9FNmFLSDNYTmtBQTs0MDpXZW9lRnJXSFItT0U2YUtIM1hOa0FBOzM5Oldlb2VGcldIUi1PRT
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {....
```

The result will return a scroll id, it can be used to get the next hits.

The Sample `scroll` Requests(`-d` _scroll_id):

```
 $ curl -XGET  'localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=1m&pretty' -d 'cXVlcnlUaGVuRmV0Y2g7NTszMTpXZW9lRnJXSFItT0U2YUtIM1hOa0FBOzMyOldlb2VGcldIUi1PRTZhS0gzWE5rQUE7MzM6V2VvZUZyV0hSLU9FNmFLSDNYT
 mtBQTszNDpXZW9lRnJXSFItT0U2YUtIM1hOa0FBOzM1Oldlb2VGcldIUi1PRTZhS0gzWE5rQUE7MDs='
```

The Official Document: [Scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)